# Does a same-day return ticket count as a "through ticket to some other country"?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, tickets, eu-citizens, caribbean, montserrat

I'm soon going to Guadeloupe, Dominica and Martinique and am considering doing a day trip from Guadeloupe to Montserrat by ferry. I do not plan on bringing my passport, as my (Swedish) ID card is valid for Guad+Dom+Mart (Guad+Mart obviously, Dom too according to their head of immigration, whom I asked via e-mail)

Montserrat remains the question, as I haven't been able to find a proper e-mail address to send a message to.

Reading through the Montserrat immigration act, it says you do **not** need a passport if being a passenger "**in transit** by sea or air who does not intend to remain in Montserrat for more than fourteen days **provided they are in possession of through tickets to some other destination**"

It's on page 71 of this document http://agc.gov.ms/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/13.01-Immigration-Act.pdf

My question is: would a same-day return ticket to Guadeloupe be acceptable for this purpose?

Comment: Seems obvious that it does to me but I have no authoritative information regarding this.

Comment: Wiki says yes https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_identity_card_(Sweden)
*It can also be used instead of a Swedish passport for entering Dominica (de facto), French overseas territories, Georgia, Montserrat ...*

Comment: "I do not plan on bringing my passport".  ...............why?

Comment: I messaged the official Monserrat FB page, asking the question. We'll see when/whether they respond (they may be on Island time) https://www.facebook.com/MNISpirit/

Comment: @JoeBlow I simply don't when not setting foot in territories where it's required. I will though unless I can get a somewhat clear reponse regarding Montserrat

Comment: @Dorothy Fun fact: it was me who put that info in the wiki article, based on info I found in Timatic

Comment: You're good :-) no word yet from Monserrat; you'd think it would be the same as the UK, as a BOT.

Comment: @Dorothy It's not, a passport is definitely required for other non-EU BOTs, as well as all Dutch territories. French and Danish territories are another story. In fact, although the Island of St Martin doesn't have a border between the French and Dutch sides, if you arrive at the Juliana Airport on the Dutch side, even if going to the French side, they will **not** let you in without a passport, whereas if arriving at Grand-Case Airport on the French side, even if going to the Dutch side, it's pefectly fine

Comment: @Crazydre you may have to take your passport, jic, unless you're content with a RT ferry excursion.

Comment: @Dorothy Yep, I just might if I get no further in this matter.

Comment: Having been to Montserrat, I'm not surprised you can't find an email address for them! You might be able to ring, if you avoid lunch. When we flew in, the immigration official who stamped us in also told us where to find our hire car, as the guest house had let him know we were coming.... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so **finally** I actually managed to reach someone, namely the lawmakers of Montserrat themselves.

A same-day return does **not** count as a "through ticket", meaning that you only qualify for that passport exemption if in transit to a third country. Timatic should highlight this more clearly IMO.

So EU ID cards (except Croatian) can be used if staying for max 14 days on the way to a third country. Otherwise, only French ID cards are accepted (for max 6 months)

Comment: This makes sense to me. Beijing offers an extended transit without visa encouraging you to spend a few days sightseeing - but you can't use it for a three day trip, it has to be a transit to a third destination. http://en.bcia.com.cn/server/notice/72visafree/72visafree_policy.shtml

Comment: Why "except Croatian"?

Comment: What if you buy a throwaway ticket and cancel it upon arrival?

Comment: @phoog probably because Croatia is the most recent EU member

Comment: @phoog Because Croatians need a visa for Montserrat. Electronic, yes, but still requires a passport apparently

Comment: @JonathanReez I'd imagine you could get sanctioned for that on exit, as really you'd be in violation of the immigration act. Not something I'd want to try out, that's for sure

Answer (score 7):

If Timatic is considered authority, it confirms this too:

> The following are exempt from holding a visa:
>   Nationals of Sweden with any proof of identity (other than a passport)
>   for a maximum stay of 14 days if they hold a confirmed **onward ticket.**
>
> Visa issuance:
>   Multiple entry E-Visa valid for 1 year can be obtained through the
>   internet, prior to departure, at https://www.immigration.ms/. Holders
>   of the E-Visa must have a passport valid for the period of intended
>   stay in Montserrat, **and a return/onward ticket.**
>
> Additional information:
>   Visitors are required to hold proof of sufficient funds to cover their
>   stay **and documents required for their next destination.**

Note that in several places return/forward is explicitly stated, meaning the people writing this indeed understood the difference.

This is also the case pretty much everywhere else you can get without visa - they require you to have a ticket *somewhere*, not necessarily the return ticket. The only exception I can think of is China, but in their case it is explicitly stated "**transit** without visa", not a "visa free entry for visitors".

Comment: This is one hell of a special case, because Timatic literally bases this quote on the document I linked (they told me), which is kind of ambiguous given that it does say "in transit"

Comment: Since the airline will consider Timatic when deciding whether to let him  aboard, this should be good enough. After all, technically you are in transit. China makes it clear the transit has to be "to a third country", and this is not the case here.

Comment: Thing is I'm taking the boat from Guadeloupe.

Comment: I don't see any problems here. If you want it to be bulletproof, buy a refundable ticket to a 3rd country leaving within 14 days, and cancel it once you leave Montserrat.

Comment: Another exception is Britain's (landside) "transit without visa" scheme, which requires that the traveler _"is genuinely in transit to another country, meaning the purpose of his visit is to travel via the UK en route to another destination country, and he is **taking a reasonable transit route**"_. Round tips plainly don't count for that. (And I suspect this is actually the more common interpretation for countries that have particularly lenient visa requirements for "transit" in particular).

Comment: Timatic _only_ covers air travel. **It does not cover land and sea travel** and has no knowledge of immigration rules for these.

Answer (score 1):

No, you would not be able to enter Montserrat using a Swedish ID card, according to a response to my PM via the Spirit of Montserrat Facebook page. Absent any other way to contact official sources, as you discovered, it would be best to carry your passport.

[Spirit of Montserrat is the official Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/MNISpirit/) for the media entities within the Government of Montserrat. The information provided will be about the government and people of the island.

My 10/2 query: During my trip to Guadeloupe, I would like to come to Monserrat for the day (round trip by ferry). Am I able to enter Montserrat using just my Swedish ID card?

And the 10/11 response: *I'm afraid not. Should you require more information contact the consular division at 1-664-491-2368.*

Comment: Your link points to a radio facebook page. There is no response to any message. Plus I doubt a radio community manager would be an authoritative source. Please quote your message and the answer, to see what it is worth.

Comment: @Vince note that OP had attempted to contact any sources available for confirmation, and this was a followup per comments. OP already planned to carry the passport.

Comment: @Dorothy Thanks for the phone number, will call it and refer to the quote in the law when asking. I'll let you know what they say

Comment: @Dorothy What a surprise, the number is no longer in Operation. Just found visa@gov.ms - will see if they reply

Comment: @Crazydre we call it Island Time :-)